# libsasl2.so.3 cannot open shared object file No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04

Running on 16.04 (x64)

```
git fetch upstream
git-remote-https: error while loading shared libraries: libsasl2.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I didn't have this issue before

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -S \`which git\``? It should return `git: /usr/bin/git`. If it does not you should remove its executable and reinstall with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall git`.

Comment: @N0rbert it does show git: /usr/bin/git I tried re installing it again anyway but I still get the same error

Comment: What is the output of `which git`?